# How to deploy SQL Scripts through Azure CI/CD?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

We have bunch of SQL Scripts (.sql files) which we are manually deploying from one Server to another Server.

All the SQL Scripts are managed through SQL Project in Azure.

How to deploy SQL Scripts through Azure CI/CD?

Comment: Can you provide some background on what research you've done, what you've tried, and what didn't work with the approaches you've tried?

Comment: @DanielMann , I have the batch file for traditional sql script deployment. I read the article from simple talk about SQL CI/CD. I was wondering, how to implement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managing database schemas and how they're promoted in your environments should be given equal consideration to application and infrastructure deployments. Here's some high-level guidelines.

1. **Source Control** - You're going to need to put your scripts in source control. If you're using Azure DevOps, use a Git repository to store all the scripts that are produced. Moreover, we need them in source control so our CI/CD tooling can get at it. If you're a DBA and this sounds weird to you, I'm sorry, you'll have to get used to it.

   1b. **Enable Pull Requests** -- Configure your source repository to only accept changes from a pull-request. This ensures that your schema changes are being reviewed before they are accepted into the repository. Improves knowledge sharing for the team and improves overall quality as it can catch mistakes before they get deployed.
2. **Security** - lock down your database so that random users can't deploy random changes. Create a dedicated account for applying database schema changes and only provide the credentials to the Continous Delivery Tool. Under this model, if it isn't in source control, it doesn't exist. Our CI/CD tool will be responsible for deploying those changes for us.
3. **Use a Tool** - and stop doing it manually! Our team decided on an opensource framework called [db-migrate](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that manages the changes to the database schemas. We chose db-migrate because it's open-source and works on a number of different platforms. Microsoft uses the [EntityFramework Code-First Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/), which db-migrate is based on.

   How Migrations work: Basically, each time you need to modify the database you create a "migration" that includes your SQL script changes.  When the tool runs against your database, it creates a table in the database to keep track of which migrations have been previously run, so it only runs any new migrations. In short, migrations should be non-destructive to prevent data loss and the scripts should be considered read-only once they've been applied to any database. (You should never change a migration sql script after it's been used; create a new migration instead)
4. **Continuous Integration** - any time a new migration is checked into source control, your CI server packages the scripts up as an artifact for the next stage.
5. **Continuous Delivery** - The continuous delivery system takes the build artifact and runs the db-migrate tool (node.js) against each target environment. The CD tool uses a dedicated SQL user account that is allowed to make database schema changes. As illustrated in #2 this should be the only way that changes are deployed.

**UPDATE: Using Entity Framework**

As you can tell from the approach listed above, I'm obviously very interested to keep database schema changes limited to a specific user account to prevent accidentally deploying the application with a user account that has unrestricted access. Your mileage may vary, but there are a few approaches you can use:

1. **Use [migrate.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe) to perform the migrations** - This tool ships with the EntityFramework and it would be possible to invoke your code-first migrations as a deployment step. This would be very similar to how I'm using db-migrate above.
2. **Script the migrations during application start-up** - You can write code in your web-application initialization logic to [perform any outstanding migrations](https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/). This is perhaps the easiest to implement but requires that you run the application with a database account that has unrestricted access. Also, if there's a problem with the database migration you won't know until the application is already deployed. From a CI/CD perspective, I'd want to fail the deployment and potentially rollback before completely messing the site up.
3. **Configure the Publishing Profile** - You can configure the publishing profile as [outlined in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to "Update the Database". This effectively adds a databaseInitializer to the web.config to update the database when the app starts up. This has similar drawbacks but at least allows you to have a different user account for applying the database changes.

[image]

Note that it's totally doable to embed your stored-procedures as resources within your migrations and then just invoke the raw sql statements from the migration:

Base Migration:

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom DbMigration with helper methods
/// </summary>
public abstract class BaseDbMigration : DbMigration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Apply a SQL statement stored in an embedded resource
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resourceName"></param>
    protected void SqlFromEmbeddedResource(string resourceName)
    {
        Assembly assembly = typeof(BaseDbMigration).Assembly;

        string baseNamespace = typeof(BaseDbMigration).Namespace;

        resourceName = baseNamespace + "." + resourceName;

        bool exists = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(r => r == resourceName).SingleOrDefault() != null;

        if (exists)
        {
            string sql = null;

            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                sql = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            base.Sql(sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Example Migration:

```
/// <summary>
/// Migration: Deploy Stored Proc
/// </summary>
public partial class CalculateTotalsV1 : BaseDbMigration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public override void Up()
    {
        base.SqlFromEmbeddedResource("sp_CalculateTotals.v1.Up.sql");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public override void Down()
    {
        base.SqlFromEmbeddedResource("sp_CalculateTotals.v1.Down.sql");
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to keep the database migrations separate from the application deployment it should go without saying that you'll want to separate your code-first migrations into their own .net assembly. This makes it easier to invoke the migration.

Comment: thank you. I am coming from development background and not with DBA skills. I am working on this stabilize the SQL deployment in the CI/CD model. I will go through points. Thanks that was well explained in detail.

Comment: thanks.. In my understanding db-migrate tool is not for MS SQL.  And also our current project is about Entity Framework - Code First Migration model. EF helps to generate table schema. I am working on bunch of SQL Procedures and constant changes in the SQL SP's.

Comment: Updated the note to include details on deploying EntityFramework Code-First migrations in the same manner as db-migrate

Comment: thanks a lot .. but i mentioned in my previous notes .. that i am working on pushing the stored procedures .. .sql files .. . Entity Framework is good from .Net application. Over here, its about having SQL as a separate project and pushing in CI/CD model

Comment: I missed that you were only concerned about stored-procs, thought you were using EF. Yes, EF can infer the table schemas from the application code and generate the SQL statements -- but it doesn't have to. You could just embed the sql files as resources and run the raw sql during the migration

Comment: that is helpful, i will have to start working on doing some test for migrating only sp's.. thanks for that